# JMeter recording - 'ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR' and 'Software caused connection abort: socket write error'

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm new in JMeter and my topic seems to be very similar to another ones already existing. However, it is not - I was trying already all the solutions for the errors that I get and nothing works :/
I have already set up all proxy settings and certificates, and it's working fine (with the same settings) on the other VM. 
Outside the recording, I can see proper 'No Internet' warning:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qkq4.png)

However, once started recording, there are errors in the console and the front end of the application does not look like originally:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGFwx.png)

Please help! I've already done all the recommendations for clearing caches, SSL, removing files in Windows32 archive and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You should try recording your script using [Blazemeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension:-Record-JMeter,-Selenium,-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium). Hope, this resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case there are differences in machines themselves, not in JMeter settings, for example this `No Internet` message most probably means that the browser is connected to JMeter's proxy server, but JMeter itself cannot connect to the internet.

Try creating a simple manual Test Plan with a single [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to open http://example.com website. If the request will be successful - you will need to double check your browser and JMeter configuration. However if you get the [UnknownHostException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html) instead it may mean that:

1. Networking configuration of the machine is incorrect (it cannot access the Internet)
2. The machine requires an upstream [Proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) in order to be able to access Internet resources so you will need to [make JMeter aware of this proxy server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) by passing appropriate command line arguments to the JMeter startup script:

   ```
   jmeter -E https -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password -N localhost
   ```

   in order to make the changes permanent you can define:

   - `http.proxyScheme`
   - `http.proxyHost`
   - `http.proxyPort`
   - `https.proxyHost`
   - `https.proxyPort`

   in *system.properties* file and `http.proxyDomain` in user.properties file, check out [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and ways of setting and overriding them